# How make a active WebPage

Tags: javascript, php, web

I have a text box in a webpage and i want when the user type something in it, display it with no refresh.

My php file that get data from user and display it:

```
<?php 
    $text = $_GET['text'];
    echo $text;
?>
```

and the html file:

```
<form method="Get">
    <input type="text" name="text">
</form>
```

How can make it type *$text* when the user type in input.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look up AJAX.

Comment: Your form doesn't have an action https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: Please Try AJAX

Answer (score 1):

What is the point use PHP and AJAX in this case? If you don't store any data from user type in database, I can not see the shuffle.

You can use simple JavaScript function to read a value of input and set it as *innerHTML* of any element.

Look on this JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="text"]').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  const input = e.target;
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = input.value;
})
```

and this HTML structure:

```
<form method="Get">
    <input type="text" name="text">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

In you types in input, it's automatically supplements **[id="result"]** with value.

This is **working demo**: https://jsbin.com/hadevocoqo/edit?html,js,output

Greetings, plum!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use javascript(AJAX) for this process.

All you need to do is keep the php file in a separate file and use AJAX to connect it.

```
<form method="Get">
<input type="text" name="text" onKeyUp="makeAjaxCall()" id="input">
    </form>



<script>
function makeAjaxCall() {
let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
if(input){
// make the ajax function call here
// Ajax response is injected into the document using innerHTML.
connectViaAJAX();
} else {
// no input is provided.
}
}



function connectViaAJAX() {
// write ajax here
}
</script>
```

There are other javascript libraries out there that you can check out
Angular: http://angular.io/

VueJs: https://vuejs.org/

ReactJs: https://reactjs.org/

and many more.

You can visit : https://w3schools.com for more programming tutorials